# using R I would like to arrange the following Excel data into a usable format for ggplot2

Tags: r

How can I create a y axis using the values under the dates without manipulating the data in Excel?

```
Client  12/21/2015  12/22/2015  12/26/2015
client1  50               60    59
client2  50               60    60
client3  51               60    61
client4  53               60    62
client5  55               60    63
client6  55               60    64
client7  51               60    65
```

Comment: What's the source of your data? And what format is that? Like Excel, R does a great job of handling data that's arranged like a spreadsheet.

Comment: look at `?tidyr::gather`

Answer (score 0):

You have got to reshape the date from wide to long format. This can be done using `gather`, as suggested in the comments:

```
library(tidyverse)
df <- read.table(header=T, check.names=F, text="
 Client  12/21/2015  12/22/2015  12/26/2015
client1  50               60    59
client2  50               60    60
client3  51               60    61
client4  53               60    62
client5  55               60    63
client6  55               60    64
client7  51               60    65") 
df <- gather(df, date, value, -Client)
```

Then

```
ggplot(df, aes(x = Client, y=value, fill = date)) + 
  geom_col()
```

Or

```
ggplot(df, aes(x = as.Date(date, "%m/%d/%Y"), y = value, color = Client)) + 
  geom_line() + 
  geom_point()
```